# Android wear Watch face installs but not shown in faces list

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I create new watch face for android wear using Android Studio. It runs in emulator. I generate signed APK and installs it manually in my phone with connected smart watch (Sony SW3). It installs successfully but it does not shown in face part of Android Wear application. also in smart watch face settings

Comment: Have you tried rebooting both devices? It does sometimes take a little time to update, especially in the Android Wear app on the phone. Otherwise, you might be missing something from your XML - please copy the relevant sections into your question. Hard to diagnose anything without some code. :^)

Comment: Try to run in smart watch alone

Answer (score 2):

When you release your app on the Play Store, the wear apk is bundled in the phone apk and is automatically sent and installed on the wearables, but on debug builds, only the handset apk is deployed to the device. You need to also install the wear apk on the wearable.

If your watch has USB support (LG G Watch, Huawei Watch, Asus Zenwatch 2...), you can plug it just like any handset, enable adb debugging and let's press the run button in Android Studio.

If your watch doesn't have USB support (Moto 360 and other induction only charging), you need to enable Bluetooth debugging (slower than through USB though). You can learn more about all of this on the official Android Developers website.